# How to I stop an infinite redirect loop?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a blog that has a redirect loop, and I can't understand htaccess too well right now (late, and needs to be done by the AM) so am hoping for a quick fix. The site is throwing 301s from xxxxx.org to xxxxx.org/index.php, and back to the beginning. The htaccess file is as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

redirect 301 /index.html http://www.lawyersclearinghouse.org/index.php
```

**The site was recently listed on google as malicious due to an iFrame injection, so please don't feel the need to visit it (cleaned, but not yet delisted)**

Comment: It's not redirecting on my machine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your rewrite conditions are combined with a logical OR so they will apply in all cases.  If the file is a plain file it will not be a directory and vice versa.

Your rule is also odd.  Are you trying to match all cases?  in that case it should presumable be .* (any string of characters) rather than . (any single character)

Answer (score 0):

Your site seems to work for me. Anyway, make sure index.php exists.